# How to increase memory on latest Wamp for MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, wamp, wampserver

Old Wamp's mysql had extra files like my_huge.ini and I would just replace it with the default my.ini in bin\mysql\mysql5.6.12\ and now I just installed latest Wamp on Win8 and it has only my.ini file.

How do I know now how to configure my PC for the my_huge.ini settings? Maybe someone knows the stats it used to be or has the actual file or something?

The default my.ini is for 32M - 64M and I am running on 8GB i3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't played with it under Win8, but I have never had a problem with modifying the .ini file by right clicking on the WAMP icon, then navigating to the PHP folder/menu-thingy and selecting php.ini.

This opens it up in notepad/textpad/some-text-editor and you make the modifications, then click on Save.

Then it is just a matter of restarting apache.

On that note, modifying the actual php.ini file in the default install folder doesn't do anything as it isn't used (though the cli.ini IS). The php file is somehow generated on the fly when wamp starts rather than using a physical file in the folder.

Edit: This is the line you want to search for:

```
; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (128MB)
; http://php.net/memory-limit
memory_limit = 512M
```

Comment: Yeah but I never did that manually I do not know what changes to do, I would just replace that my_huge.ini that's all.